# Pandas convert to percent, groupby, and transform

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` with observations for a number of variables for a number of "Teams". I have converted the values of the columns I want to alter to binary values  and would like to take the `DataFrame` I have, groupby the "Teams" while aggregating into percentages and transform the table to make the "Teams" rows become the columns.

```
df1
     Teams     X    V1    V2    V3    V4
 0   Team 1   8    1     1     0     0
 1   Team 2   9    1     0     1     0
 2   Team 3   6    1     0     0     1
 3   Team 1   10   0     1     1     0
```

This is what I have tried so far, but I get an AttributeError: "DataFrame" object has no attribute 'value_counts'.

```
def percent(df, column):
    zero = df[column].value_counts()[0]
    one = df[column].value_counts()[1]
    perc = one/(zero+one)
    return {column:perc}

cols = [V1, V2, V3, V4]
df1 = df1.groupby('Teams').agg(percent(df1, cols))
df1 = df1.T
```

Desired Output:

```
df1
       Team 1    Team 2    Team 3
X        18        9         6
V1      0.25      0.34      0.2
V2      0.1       0.3       0.8
V3      0.9       0.3       0.12
V4      0.23      0.5       0.1
```

Any suggestions on how I can make this work?

Edit: I believe that the issue is the columns are not being iterated over when I call the `percent` function within `agg`. I have also tried:

```
percent_cols = []
for value in cols:
    percent_cols.append(percent(df1, value))
```

This works in the sense that it returns a dictionary of column names and percentages but it defeats my ability to groupby "Team"

Comment: Can you post an example of your desired output?

Comment: What should percent be equal to? What happened to `d` between your input and output?

Comment: Afraid I don't understand what you mean when you ask what percent should be equal to. Can you clarify? And sorry the loss of `d` can be ignored. Was just trying to create an example that demonstrated I couldn't just apply a function to the `DataFrame` as a whole but needed to specifically select columns. The `X` column I have can be handled with sum() so I will edit to reflect that.

Comment: What about `df.groupby('Teams')['V1','V2','V3','V4'].mean().apply(lambda x: x/sum(x)).T``. How far is that from your desired result?

Comment: Sure... how is percent defined? What divided by what else? You have to define that. It isn't clear how you are calculating the values in your desired output.

To count how many times a value occurs in a column, you can use something like `sum(df.V1 == 0)`. `value_counts()` returns a pandas Series.

Comment: It should be `zero = df[column].value_counts()[0]`. If I do `df1['V1'].value_counts()[0]` it will return `0`  `738`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# group teams
df = df.groupby('Teams').sum()

# returns:
        X  V1  V2  V3  V4
Teams                    
Team 1 18   1   2   1   0
Team 2  9   1   0   1   0
Team 3  6   1   0   0   1

# find percentages
for c in ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V4']:
    df1[c] /= df1[c].sum()

# rotate
df1 = df1.T

# returns:
Teams     Team 1    Team 2    Team 3
X      18.000000  9.000000  6.000000
V1      0.333333  0.333333  0.333333
V2      1.000000  0.000000  0.000000
V3      0.500000  0.500000  0.000000
V4      0.000000  0.000000  1.000000
```

My results do not match "Desired Output" because your percents are not sum up to 1 (as they should)